# web2py date & time picker issue

Tags: python, date, time, web2py

I am trying to get the AJAX / JQUERY UI element in Web2Py for the date time picker to work for my forms from within a smart grid table.  It doesn't seem to function as expected in the documentation.  I just get a text entry field that doesn't display the picker at all and I can't figure out why.
The code I have created the field with is this:

```
Field('temp_date', type='date', requires = IS_DATE(format=('%d-%m-%Y'))),
```

I have also tried it without any formatting and I still get the same result.
the forms are generated by the Smartgrid when I click the 'edit' button so not sure if that ends to be changed somehow.
What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong w/ your creation/use of smartgrid?  Had to say, as you haven't shown anything about it.

Comment: Are you saying you are expecting the default web2py date picker to appear, or are you attempting to use a Jquery UI or other third-party date picker? If the latter, how are you setting up the date picker?

Comment: I am expecting the default web2py date picker to appear really.  I don't think there is anything overly odd about how I am creating the smart grid. The code is: `grid4=SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.auth_user, constraints = dict(auth_user=query), links=links, linked_tables=['user_server', 'auth_membership'], maxtextlength = 80)`

Comment: I would also note that it doesn't seem to work via the database administration page either, so something is going wrong somewhere.  I am using version: 2.14.3-stable+timestamp.2016.03.26.23.02.02

Comment: I upgraded to the latest build 2.14.6 and it solved the problem.  I did the upgrade because the CAS functionality was also broken in the version I was using.  Hope this helps others out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest build 2.14.6 and it solved the problem. I did the upgrade because the CAS functionality was also broken in the version I was using. Hope this helps others out too.

Comment: Quick update, as it started failing again on some pages.  Essentially, the template page started to lose the reference to the query includes.  This was because I was using iFrames I think.  So to sort out the issue I added the content of the web2py_ajax.html as a header into the views that were being used in the iframes (so literally copy and paste the content into your view.  This sorted it out.